# Blazored Modal modals appear above the calling page rather than overlaying the page

Tags: blazor, blazored

I'm using Blazored Modal modals in a Blazor server app and the modals are positioned above the calling page rather than overlaying it.

App.razor:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <CascadingBlazoredModal Class="custom-blazored-modal">
        <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(GridLayout)" />
            </Found>
            <NotFound>
                <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(GridLayout)">
                    <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
                </LayoutView>
            </NotFound>
        </Router>
    </CascadingBlazoredModal>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

site.css:

```
.custom-blazored-modal {
    display: flex;
    z-index: 102;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #F5EFE7;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 4px solid #660624;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

Example of method to display a modal:

```
    // Open the modal dialog to add a new notebook.
    async Task AddNotebookAsync_Click()
    {
        // Add a notebook via a dialog.
        var parameters = new ModalParameters();
        var options = new ModalOptions()
            {
                HideCloseButton = true,
                DisableBackgroundCancel = true
            };
        var addNotebookModal = Modal.Show<AddNotebookModal>(null, parameters, options);

        var result = await addNotebookModal.Result;

        // If the user cancelled, exit.
        if (result.Cancelled)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.StateHasChanged();

        return;
    }
```

Example of what is displayed:

[image: Example of modal positioned above the calling page]

The code appears to be virtually the same as in other apps where it works (the modal overlays the calling page).
I tried changing the z-index but with no effect.

Comment: Some things I notice: Why are you creating a ModelsParameter object, not populating it but still passing it to the ModalService? Why are you calling StateHasChanged? Does this modal update data via a cascading parameter or something? It's hard to tell from what you provided. Why pass null in the title constructor field for the modal. In ModalOptions you can set: HideHeader = true.  Any reason for the unnecessary return on your AddNotebookAsync_Click() method?

Comment: Display flex is why

Comment: @Waragi - Thanks for your comments. There are reasons for all of the items you mentioned. Do you have any insight into why the modal is not overlaying the calling page?

Comment: @MisterMagoo - Thanks for the suggestion, but 'display: flex;' appears in the custom-blazored-modal class for another app and the modal overlays the calling page there as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using CSS Isolation in your app as that can easily be forgotten with Blazor and break many things.

> Blazored Modal uses CSS isolation. If your application is already
> using CSS isolation then the styles for Modal will be included
> automatically and you can skip this step. However, if your application
> isn't using isolated CSS, you will need to add a reference to the CSS
> bundle. You can checkout the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#css-isolation-bundling) for additional details.

```
<link href="{YOUR APP ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: If I have the line you suggested already, do you have other follow-up suggestions to check?  In my case, everything worked fine with dotnet6, and I'm trying to upgrade to dotnet7 on client and server.  The wasm app works, but the modal popups no longer overlay.